# Disable just the switch snippet in resharper 8 (c#)

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

I find that the default VS 2013 switch snippet works a lot better than the one from resharper. any way to just disabe that?

Answer (score 12):

I see a couple of ways to get this:

1. With ReSharper IntelliSense

   - Uncheck 'switch' here: ReSharper | Templates Explorer | Live Templates | C#;
   - Type 'switch' in code editor;
   - Hit 'Esc' to hide IntelliSense popup;
   - Hit 'Tab' to insert VS "switch" code snippet.
2. With VS IntelliSense

   - Uncheck 'switch' here: ReSharper | Templates Explorer | Live Templates | C#
   - Select 'Visual Studio' here: ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | General;
   - Apply [this](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545129-Visual-Studio-IntelliSense-is-broken-after-uninstalling-suspending-ReSharper) to enable VS IntelliSense;
   - Type 'switch' in code editor;
   - Hit 'Tab' twice to insert VS "switch" code snippet.

Comment: For info it's ReSharper | Tools | Templates Explorer | Live Templates | C# in ReSharper 10