# Visual Studio "if" snippet initially won't recognize variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a noob question.
When I use the built in visual studio "if" snippet the expression in the parentheses won't initially recognize any of the variables in my class. I have tried google without much luck.

Here are my steps to reproduce:

1. I type "if" - the if statement snippet appears in my intellisense.
2. I hit enter or tab - the if statement is added. There is now a red box inside the parentheses that says "expr".
3. I now attempt to start typing my variable - nothing is found in the intellisense window.
   [image]

I have found that if I delete the red box and then move the cursor outside of the parentheses then go back inside the parentheses, the intellisense will then pick up the variable.

My question is: Is there a better way to use the if snippet with variables? Is this my my computer?

Comment: This works fine for me. Have you tried closing and restarting VS? It tends to be a bit buggy at times :).

Comment: Yeah I have. I still get the same results. I have visual studio on another computer at home. So I'll check when I get back there.

Comment: Also I am using VS2017.

Comment: Go to `Tools->Code Snippets->Manager-> Language: CSharp` and check if there is any snippet that is mapped to `if`

Comment: Are you using ReSharper?

Comment: @JonathonChase Yes. I am using ReSharper.

Comment: This is the ReSharper `if` live template being used over the default snippet that comes with VS. I'm not sure why it's intellisense is failing so hard. You can follow instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170329/disable-just-the-switch-snippet-in-resharper-8-c) substituting `if` for `switch`. Older version, but should hold up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jonathon Chase for pointing me in the right direction. This seems to be an issue with the ReSharper `if` live template. I would assume some folks like it better that way. Looking through the JetBrains documentation I was able to make the template work the way I wanted.

Here's what I did to fix this issue:

1. Navigate to ReSharper > Tools > Templates Explorer
2. Select C# and then find the if template (not the #if template)
3. Change `$expr$` to `$expression$`

Now save and it should work as expected.