# In ReSharper Templates Explorer - What is the difference between the #if and if templates?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am playing around with the live templates for C# in ReSharper. I started doing this because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528946/visual-studio-if-snippet-initially-wont-recognize-variables) question. When I get the the ReSharper templates explorer in Visual Studio, I see that there is a `#if` template and also an `if` template. My question is why?

I have read through the ReSharper help [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Templates_Explorer__Live_Templates_CSHARP.html#Live_if_CSHARP), but that doesn't really shed much light on it (for me). I have also tried un-checking each template. It seems like the `if` template is the ReSharper if snippet, but I can't figure out what the `#if` template is for.

Is this the Visual Studio if snippet? If so, why don't I see both in the intellisense widow?

I know this is a really small issue, but I just want to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#if` is a [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) where as `if` is a C# [selection statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else)

Example:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

vs

```
bool condition = true;

if (condition)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The variable is set to true.");
}
```